# Латинский = Праславянский?

Tags: лингвистика

Кто знает, объясните, пожалуйста, выдержку из статьи Фасмера, где он сообщает:

Праслав. *LЬGЪKЪ родственно лат. LEVIS "легкий, быстрый".

Какие основания считать, что LЬGЪKЪ родственно LEVIS?
Из чего это вытекает?

(Добавим только - сам Фасмер в своей статье никаких доказательств собственному утверждению не приводит).

Comment: Так  вы бы выдержку привели. Ссылочу. А то получается как-то очень не по-людски.

Comment: Не проблема. Вот здесь в статье под тем же словом ЛЕГКИЙ, о котором и спрашиваю:

http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-6782.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Из чего это вытекает?
> > (Добавим только - сам Фасмер в своей статье никаких доказательств собственному утверждению не приводит).

Вы вообще понимаете, чем словарь отличается от монографии? Читайте монографии, тогда поймете. А до этого читайте много-много учебной литературы. **Много-много**.

Comment: Это не ответ.

Comment: Хорошо, без Фасмера, можете показать почему праслав. *LЬGЪKЪ родственно лат. LEVIS ("легкий, быстрый")?

Comment: Нет, конечно. Для этого надо быть специалистом или иметь желание много гуглить. Но законы звуковых соответствий давно и хорошо известны, насколько я знаю.

Я уже говорил: я не специалист, поэтому Фасмера мне обсуждать не с руки. Вы тоже не специалист (еще какой неспециалист!), однако считаете, что имеете на это право. И это выглядит очень забавно.

Comment: Почему я не имею право задавать вопросы по этимологии?
Что Вас забавляет?
Вы уверены что "ЗАКОНЫ ЗВУКОВЫХ СООТВЕТСТВИЙ" - работают во всех соответствующих статьях Фасмера?

Comment: Вы не задаете вопросы, вы утверждаете. Посмотрите на заголовок вашего вопроса, на эту дикую чушь.

Comment: Послушайте, постарайтесь быть тактичнее и точнее, если Вам не трудно.
И заголовок и само содержание темы у меня - имеют форму вопроса:

Латинский = Праславянский? 
Кто знает, объясните, пожалуйста... 
Какие основания считать, что...

Comment: Вот именно что форму. Только форму вопроса. В смысле – знак стоит.

А вам не кажется, что на форуме, где подавляющее большинство – сильные любители и профессионалы, задавать подобные вопросы не то что неуместно, а я даже не знаю... Попробуйте на математическом форуме задать "вопрос" в форме утверждения... скажем, о рациональности числа пи.

Comment: Что-то нас не туда заносит, уважаемый.
На мат.форуме мы задаем математические вопросы, в том числе о происхождении константы ПИ. И любой математик не посчитает зазорным напомнить кто, когда и как его получил. Никаких тайн. Всё прозрачно.
А вот на площадке по Русскому языку - задаем вопросы по происхождению и объяснению слов.

Есть такая дисциплина - этимология. Понимаете?
Чего скрывать-то? Что за тайны такие вселенские?

Comment: Это вы считаете, что от вас Фасмер и другие ученые скрывают некие "вселенские тайны". На самом деле тайн никаких нет, просто предмет не "прозрачный", как вы изволите выражаться, а очень и очень трудный.

(Кстати, "русский язык" пишется со строчной, несмотря на *огромадную* вашу к нему якобы любовь).

Comment: Этимология - предмет непрозрачный.

Я так и знал.

А выражение Русский язык надо писать с заглавной, хотя бы из уважения к форуму, если иначе влом.

Comment: Потратьте хотя бы лет пять на изучение (это минимум) — и он, предмет, перестанет быть для вас "непрозрачным". Но вы хотите всего и сразу — тогда извините.

>> Русский язык надо писать с заглавной, хотя бы из уважения к форуму

У-у-у... Какая уж там этимология, если вы с обыкновенной грамматикой сильно не в ладах.

Comment: Значит, по существу ничего не скажете.
Жаль. Одними пререканиями сыт не будешь.

Comment: Нянек тут нет - я уж вам давно говорил.

Answer (score 2):

> Какие основания считать, что LЬGЪKЪ родственно LEVIS?

Изучение языков позволило воссоздать слова дописьменной речи. К таким воссозданным словам относится и *LЬGЪKЪ, звёздочка перед словом это как раз и означает. Таким образом учёным удалось воссоздать многие слова древних языков, помимо этого были выявлены законы, по которым звуки одного языка переходили (и переходят) в другой язык. Именно на основании этих переходов Фасмер и сделал свои выводы.

Если проводить аналогию с людскими семьями, то эти два слова в своеобразном двоюродном, если не в троюродном родстве. От слова в общеиндоевропейском, независимо друг от друга появились в латинском - *levis*, а в праславянском - *lьgъкъ.

Всё это долгая и кропотливая работа, требующая огромного количества знаний. Учитывая же ещё и то, что несмотря на трудность освоения этимологии, дохода она приносит немного, учёных-этимологов очень мало. Чем и пользуются разные спекулянты от языка, вроде Алексеева, Задорного и иже с ними.

Comment: Хороший ответ, Марк. Я ждал подобного.
О трудностях и бескорыстии лингвистов мне хорошо известно.

Однако, учитывая проведенную языковедами многолетнюю работу по этимологизации русского словаря, я всё же надеялся, что имею сегодня право получить от их представителя ответ на вопрос: Какую связь находит лингвистика между LЬGЪKЪ и LEVIS ?

Comment: @Федя, добавил в ответ второй абзац.